# How to get down 'foreach' to display 3 results from each category in PHP?

Tags: php, html, for-loop

I have the code for a Ecommerce template that i'm doing on for opensource. . .

Can you check this out ! That the stores are being displayed 3 in a row and in n number ! ie.., all the rows are being displayed.

I have a piece of code that fetches data from the Db and displays the store info . ..

**I just want the foreach to be restricted to 3 results only . . . and i do also need a more button depecting it to other stores like " More>> " in the bottom**

```
  <?php 
  if(count($this->store_list)>0){
            foreach($this->store_list as $store){
            ?>
   <div id="menu">         
  <span class="cons_title fl"><a href="<?php echo PATH.'store/'.$store->title_url.'.html'; ?>"><h2><?php echo ucfirst($store->name); ?></h2></a></span>

             <div class="cons_bot fl clr">

                  <ul>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->address1; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->address2; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->area_name; ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo ucfirst($store->city_name); ?>,</h4></li>
                    <li><h4><?php echo $store->pin; ?></h4></li>
                    <li><h4>PH:</h4><h4><?php echo $store->phone; ?></h4></li>
                  </ul>
                  </div>   <?php
   }
       ?>
```

Comment: Just implement a counting variable, increment it each pass through the loop, and break out if you reach 3.

Answer (score 3):

Change this...

```
foreach($this->store_list as $store){
            ?>
```

to this...

```
$number_output = 0;
foreach($this->store_list as $store){
    $number_output++;
    if($number_output > 3) break;
            ?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You should add a LIMIT clause to your database query:

```
SELECT address1, address2, area_name, city_name, pin, phone from TABLE where 1 = 1 LIMIT 3;
```

That will only retrieve 3 records so you can keep your PHP the same.

Comment: While that would work, I think for the sake of readability and being able to modify it later, using a counter variable makes more sense..

Comment: I completely disagree, you're adding unnecessary overhead with a counter variable, and bloating your code for no real reason. Not to mention pulling hundreds of rows to only use 3 is silly. Only pull the rows you need!

Comment: This makes the assumption that the only thing being pulled by the DB query is a one-row-per-store result set. Given that the thing being iterated over in the OP is `$this->store_list`, that may not actually be the case.

Comment: I totally agree with @Developer . The only moment should be noticed is that topic starter wants a _More_ button to show more records. It can be solved by implementing either an Ajax request (which can be considered redundant) or just extending the limit to `3 + n` rows, where `n` is the desired number of additional rows to display by means of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

have the for each loop to break after three attempts..

```
<?php  
  if(count($this->store_list)>0){ 
  $ctr =1;
        foreach($this->store_list as $store){ 
          if($ctr == 3) break;
        ?> 
   <div id="menu">          
  <span class="cons_title fl"><a href="<?php echo PATH.'store/'.$store->title_url.'.html'; ?>"><h2><?php echo ucfirst($store->name); ?></h2></a></span> 

         <div class="cons_bot fl clr"> 

              <ul> 
                <li><h4><?php echo $store->address1; ?>,</h4></li> 
                <li><h4><?php echo $store->address2; ?>,</h4></li> 
                <li><h4><?php echo $store->area_name; ?>,</h4></li> 
                <li><h4><?php echo ucfirst($store->city_name); ?>,</h4></li> 
                <li><h4><?php echo $store->pin; ?></h4></li> 
                <li><h4>PH:</h4><h4><?php echo $store->phone; ?></h4></li> 
              </ul> 
              </div>   <?php 
  $ctr++; } 
   ?>
```

Comment: and i do also need a more button depecting it to other stores like " More>> " in the bottom

Answer (score 0):

Add this: `$countvar=array();`

Then, every time do this:

```
if(empty($countvar[$store->category]))$countvar[$store->category]=1;
else{if($countvar[$store->category]<3){$countvar[$store->category]++; [DISPLAY THE THINGS]}}
```

that's for the case when you list ALL stores in one place. If you do it for category, other solutions work well.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (array_slice ($this->store_list, 0, 3) as $store)
```